# Make a hidden heading visible in table of content

Tags: asciidoc

I want to make a heading in the content invisible but show it in the table of content (in PDF output).

```
// here should be a heading line, that should only be visible in the TOC.
[width="100%", cols="1h,2"]
|===
|Modulname |...
|Synopsis |...
|Fachliche Änderungen |...
|Änderungen der Installation / Konfiguration |...
|===
```

Actually I only know the other way around using `[discrete]`. Hiding the heading in the TOC is not what I want.

Using:

```
λ asciidoctor-pdf -V
Asciidoctor PDF 1.6.2 using Asciidoctor 2.0.17 [https://asciidoctor.org]
Runtime Environment (ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x64-mingw-ucrt]) (lc:IBM437 fs:UTF-8 in:UTF-8 ex:UTF-8)
```

Comment: Is this for PDF generation? You could try the [`%notitle` option](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/notitle/) - it doesn't work for HTML and I cannot test the PDF generator.

Comment: PDF, yes. `[%notitle]` before the heading line doesn't do anything here. It's still present in body and toc.

Answer (score 1):

The way that Asciidoc constructs its ToC does not permit the kind of granular control over visibility that you seek.

You would need to manually construct a ToC instead of using the auto-generated ToC to achieve the visibility that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible when converting to PDF, but first [you should update asciidoctor-pdf to the version 2](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/2207).

```
gem install asciidoctor-pdf
```

Then you can use the `notitle` option as described [here](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/notitle/). In your case you could write:

```
= Document Title
:toc:

== Visible heading

[%notitle] 
=== Table, unvisible heading

[width="100%", cols="1h,2"]
|===
|Modulname |...
|Synopsis |...
|Fachliche Änderungen |...
|Änderungen der Installation / Konfiguration |...
|===
```

Comment: I have to stay on a version which is supported by Docker too. And the latest pdf version provided by "docker-asciidocotor" is 1.6.2. (docker-asciidocotor 1.18). But thanks for that. I'll have to wait for it.